# Writing an R package depending on differing packages per architecture

Tags: r, package

I want to build a package that involves loading data from mysql using different packages depending on the user's system.

For a windows user it would be through an ODBC connection via package RODBC, while a linux/mac user would use the RMySQL package.

In a script, the following works very well:

```
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
library(RMySQL)
} else {
  library(RODBC)
}
```

Now I would like to have these packages loaded at the loading of my package.
I would normally add it in the DESCRIPTION file, under 'Depends:', but this doesn't allow the optional clause.

What is the best way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usual way to solve this is via the `.onLoad` function (see `?.onLoad` or `help(".onLoad")`).

[Section 1.6.3](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Load-hooks) of the Writing R Extension Manuals gives an overview. Perhaps someone else can point you to a good example, I haven't used it so far.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first package and I must confess I didn't read the Writing R Extension Manuals so far.

Comment: @cafe876 Then you should do so. At least the chapters that appear relevant to what you want to do based on the table of contents.