# Platform neutral way to check if a program exists (e.g. pdfcrop) while creating vignette

Tags: r, package

I have a vignette which uses `pdfcrop`.

This is not going to be available on every computer or OS: The R maintainers have told me that `pdfcrop` is on their Debian systems, but apparently not others, for example.  So I'd like to include in the vignette some logic to figure out if this program is available and use it if possible (I'm using `knitr` to build the vignette and hence `knit_hooks$set(crop = hook_pdfcrop)` to activate it).

I know I can use `.Platform` to get the OS, and if I'm on unix then I can use `which pdfcrop` via `system()` to tell me where/if the program is installed, but I don't know how to make this process general for OSX, linux, Windows etc, and I'm not sure how to properly grab the return value of `which` or the corresponding commands for other platforms.

Put another way, I'm trying to do something like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325198/writing-an-r-package-depending-on-differing-packages-per-architecture) but I'm not checking for `R` packages, I'm checking for non-R programs.  I'm turning to SO since I have neither the knowledge nor the platforms to check it on.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14366406/1270695

Comment: And an answer I posted to another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971683/1270695

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for those cross-refs.  I did not see those appear in the 'related answers' area as I composed the question, nor did I find those in my initial search.  That's probably due to the frequency of the word 'which' in many contexts is unrelated to what I was looking for.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

R has a function `Sys.which()` for just this purpose. It is, in the words of its help page, "an interface to the system command ‘which’, or to an emulation on Windows".

Here's what a call to it looks like on my own Windows machine:

```
Sys.which("pdfcrop")
#                                              pdfcrop 
# "C:\\PROGRA~2\\MIKTEX~1.9\\miktex\\bin\\pdfcrop.exe"
```

To test whether an executable exists, you could do something like this:

```
Sys.which("pdfcrop") != ""
# pdfcrop 
#    TRUE 

Sys.which("pdfpop") != ""
# pdfpop 
#  FALSE
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that one, and needed it as well in a project. Adopted.